# WPF туннелирование событий

Tags: c#, wpf

```
<Canvas>
    <Canvas Background="Transparent" MouseDown="OnDown1"/>
    <Canvas Background="Transparent" MouseDown="OnDown2"/>
    <Canvas Background="Transparent" MouseDown="OnDown3"/>
</Canvas>
```

Отрабатывает только событие OnDown3, а как заставить получить события от других канвасов?

Comment: У вас именно такой код, без установки размеров?

Comment: У меня с вашим кодом вовсе ничего не отрабатывает. Попробуйте дать воспроизводящий пример.

Answer (score 0):

`MouseDown` – это bubbling событие, которые поднимается **вверх** по визуальному дереву.

```
<Canvas MouseDown="OnMouseDown">
    <Canvas Background="Transparent" />
    <Canvas Background="Transparent" />
    <Canvas Background="Transparent" />
</Canvas>
```

Получить источник события можно так:

```
private void OnMouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs args)
{
    var source = args.OriginalSource as Canvas;
}
```

Comment: bubbling - пузырьковое =)